# Sorting data by timestamp in Firebase Realtime Database (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to sort my data in Firebase Realtime Database based on their timestamp. Latest data needs to be at the very top. How can I do this using orderByChild?

This is my code when fetching the database:

```
function GetAllDataRealtime() {

    const dbRef = ref(database, 'Users');

    onValue(dbRef,(snapshot) => {
        var Users = [];
        snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
            Users.push(userSnapshot.val());
        });

        AddAllITemsToTable(Users);
    })
}
window.onload = GetAllDataRealtime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
ref.orderByChild("timestamp").on("value", (value) => { ...
```

Comment: Exactly where should i place this line of code?

Comment: Let me know if this works for you (I'm sorry I don't know how to format)

`function GetAllDataRealtime() {
const dbRef = ref(database, 'Users').orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(100);
onValue(dbRef,(snapshot) => { var Users = []; snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {Users.push(userSnapshot.val());});AddAllITemsToTable(Users);})}
window.onload = GetAllDataRealtime;`

Comment: Didn't work, getting an error saying that "ref(...).orderByChild is not a function".

Comment: const dbRef = query(ref(database, 'Users'), orderByChild('timestamp'), limitToLast(100)); worked for me but unfortunately, i needed the latest data to be on top of my table instead of the bottom